# Explain theory that a union with unnamed struct [Already Closed]

Tags: c, linux

```
union {
    __int64 bigint;
    struct {
        unsigned long low;
        long high;
    };
} offbytes;
```

I am not sure what the meaning of above code?

__int64, unsigned long, long all is 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsigned long` and `long` are not always 8 bytes. Many compilers offer 4-bytes `long` integers. I bet that this is the case with your example.

In this context, you can use the union like this:

```
offbytes a;
a.bigint = 0x0123456789abcdef;
printf("%x %x\n", a.high, a.low);
```

The result is:

```
1234567  89abcdef
```

Warning: This code is not portable, due to big/little endian considerations.

Answer (score 1):

You can access offbytes two ways :

```
offbytes.bigint = 0xFFFFFF;
printf("%ld %ld\n", offbytes.low, offbytes.high);
```

The size of the union is 16 bytes (it's the size of it's larger component).

If you write/read in offbytes.bigint, you'll write/read all 16 bytes at once.
If you write/read in offbytes.high or offbytes.low, you'll have either the lower 8 bytes or the higher 8 bytes.

Comment: i am a newbie of c, the low and bigint all is 8 bytes,the high will always zero?

Comment: Edited my response to explain.